# C# SSIS scripting - trying to save results to sql server table

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new to C#. I need to do some fancy manupulation of a really bad file and then save the results to a table. They are just customer comments but are important for finance. I am able to transfer the file to an SQL table with a regular task. I then use a script to read the file (no problem), manupulate the data (no problem) but am unable to save the results back to an SQL table. I can save the results to an arraylist and save it as a txt file (no problem). Here is the code that is not working. (sorry for the bad indent)

MDTEMP2=ADO.NET connection

```
for (int d = 0; d < comDataRecNo.Length; d++)
{
  SqlConnection myCnx3 = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["MDTEMP2"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
SqlCommand writeCommentSQL = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[cspc2_commentswip] ([Customer No_],[Comment]) VALUES(@CustNo, @Comm)", myCnx3);

writeCommentSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustNo", comDataCustNo[d]);
writeCommentSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comm", comDataComment[d]);

try
{
myCnx3.Open();
writeCommentSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCnx3.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
}
```

...here is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0rKu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

there are several mistakes here

```
SqlConnection myCnx3 = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["MDTEMP2"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
```

You are reusing the same connection object which might be shared else where in the application. Don't do that, just create new connection object and dispose them after use. .NET uses something called connection pool to manager DB connection for you, you don't have to worry about reusing existing object for performance.

```
try
{
    myCnx3.Open();
    writeCommentSQL.ExecuteNonQuery(); //What if this throws exception?
    myCnx3.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

if the execute non query line throws exception the connection will never get closed. You should wrap your connection in using statement like

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Steve, myCnx3 and MDTEMP2 are only used in this section of code, is this what you meant? I did try the using but got the same error. My breakpoints show me that it goes from myCnx3.Open() and then to the Exception.

Comment: @CarolineRoy you must have opened the connection somewhere else without closing it.

Answer (score 0):

The AcquireConnection seems to open the connections... The below now works

```
 for (int d = 0; d < comDataRecNo.Length; d++)
                {

                    using (SqlConnection myCnx3 = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["MDTEMP2"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection))
                    {
                        SqlCommand writeCommentSQL = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[cspc2_commentswip] ([Customer No_],[Comment]) VALUES(@CustNo, @Comm)", myCnx3);

                        writeCommentSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustNo", comDataCustNo[d]);
                        writeCommentSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comm", comDataComment[d]);

                        writeCommentSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        myCnx3.Close();
                    } 
                }
```